# How can I get the type(c1) -> list, not type str

Tags: python

sorry for that I'm noob T.T

```
import numpy as np

import json

import ast

import itertools

data1 = b'[{"id":"1","array1_1":"0","array1_2":"1","array2_1":"2","array2_2":"3","array3_1":"44","array3_2":"55"},{"id":"asd","array1_1":"234","array1_2":"[[0, 26, 60, 45], [0, -45, 45]]","array2_1":"[[23, 345], [543, 321]]","array2_2":"jytj","array3_1":"5","array3_2":"6"},{"id":"bb","array1_1":"bbb","array1_2":"ad","array2_1":"[[23, 345], [543, 321]]","array2_2":"[[0, 45], [45]]","array3_1":"[[34, 45], [66, 88]]","array3_2":"sfw"},{"id":"aa","array1_1":"aa","array1_2":"[[0, 26, 60, 45], [0, -45, 45]]","array2_1":"gfd","array2_2":"[[0, 45], [45]]","array3_1":"sdf","array3_2":"[[26, 60], [0], [56, 34, 45]]"},{"id":"ss","array1_1":"00","array1_2":"[[0, 45], [0, -45, 45], [0, -45, 45, -26]]","array2_1":"[[31, 233], [152, 151], [190, 204], [205, 87], [231, 48], [255, 194]]","array2_2":"[[0, 45], [45], [45], [26, 45, 63], [45], [0, 26, 45, 63]]","array3_1":"[[29, 194], [32, 234], [165, 229], [232, 46], [258, 190]]","array3_2":"[[45], [0, 45], [0, 26, 45], [0, -63, 45, 63], [0, 26, 45]]"}]'

data2 = data1.decode()

data3 = {"key" : [data2]}

s = json.dumps(data3)

data4 = str.encode(s)

data5 = json.loads(data4)

data6 = data5['key']

data7 = data6[0]

data8 = ast.literal_eval(data7)



d0 = [d['id']for d in data8]

d1 = [d['array1_1']for d in data8]

d2 = [d['array1_2']for d in data8]

d3 = [d['array2_1']for d in data8]

d4 = [d['array2_2']for d in data8]

d5 = [d['array3_1']for d in data8]

d6 = [d['array3_2']for d in data8]

da = [d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6]

for x in zip(*da):
    y = list(x)

a1 = y[0]

a2 = y[1]

a3 = y[2]

a4 = y[3]

a5 = y[4]

a6 = y[5]

b1 = np.array(a1)

b2 = np.array(a2)

b3 = np.array(a3)

b4 = np.array(a4)

b5 = np.array(a5)

b6 = np.array(a6)

c1 = b2.tolist()

c2 = b4.tolist()

c4 = b6.tolist()

print(type(c1))
```

when I use print(list(c1))

shell shows me

```
['[', '[', '0', ',', ' ', '4', '5', ']', ',', ' ', '[', '0', ',', ' ', '-', '4', '5', ',', ' ', '4', '5', ']', ',', ' ', '[', '0', ',', ' ', '-', '4', '5', ',', ' ', '4', '5', ',', ' ', '-', '2', '6', ']', ']']
```

I just want `[[0, 45], [0, -45, 45], [0, -45, 45, -26]]` like this and type must be list

Comment: We have no idea what you're trying to accomplish with this code, the code itself is too long, you don't explain the logic of your algorithm, and the question is very badly formatted. In short - it's impossible to help you. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

> I just want `[[0, 45], [0, -45, 45], [0, -45, 45, -26]]` like this and
>   type must be list

I am a bit shocked on how complex your code looks, so the first thing I did was looking at your input data, like this:

```
[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "array1_1":"0",
        "array1_2":"1",
        "array2_1":"2",
        "array2_2":"3",
        "array3_1":"44",
        "array3_2":"55"
    },

    {
        "id":"asd",
        "array1_1":"234",
        "array1_2":"[[0, 26, 60, 45], [0, -45, 45]]",
        "array2_1":"[[23, 345], [543, 321]]",
        "array2_2":"jytj",
        "array3_1":"5",
        "array3_2":"6"
    },

    {
        "id":"bb",
        "array1_1":"bbb",
        "array1_2":"ad",
        "array2_1":"[[23, 345], [543, 321]]",
        "array2_2":"[[0, 45], [45]]",
        "array3_1":"[[34, 45], [66, 88]]",
        "array3_2":"sfw"
    },

    {
        "id":"aa",
        "array1_1":"aa",
        "array1_2":"[[0, 26, 60, 45], [0, -45, 45]]",
        "array2_1":"gfd",
        "array2_2":"[[0, 45], [45]]",
        "array3_1":"sdf",
        "array3_2":"[[26, 60], [0], [56, 34, 45]]"
    },

    {
        "id":"ss",
        "array1_1":"00",
        "array1_2":"[[0, 45], [0, -45, 45], [0, -45, 45, -26]]",
        "array2_1":"[[31, 233], [152, 151], [190, 204], [205, 87], [231, 48], [255, 194]]",
        "array2_2":"[[0, 45], [45], [45], [26, 45, 63], [45], [0, 26, 45, 63]]",
        "array3_1":"[[29, 194], [32, 234], [165, 229], [232, 46], [258, 190]]",
        "array3_2":"[[45], [0, 45], [0, 26, 45], [0, -63, 45, 63], [0, 26, 45]]"
    }
]
```

The following observations:

- Your input data, while `bytes` `b''`, is a perfect '`string` of `list` of `dictionaries`'
- It seemed to me that you want `id:'ss'` and `array1_2` values

With `eval()` you can make your input data (string representing list) into a list after `decode()`

Here an example:

```
# no imports needed

def get_my_values(data: bytes, 
                  key: str, 
                  key_v: str, 
                  req: str,
                  codec: str = 'utf-8') -> str:
    '''
    data  = bytes representing a string representing a list of dictionaries
    key   = key to use to select the element/dictionary of the list
    key_v = value to match for the key to select the element/dictionary
    req   = required key of the dictionary to return its values
    codec = codec to use for decode(), defaults to 'utf-8' when omitted
    '''
    l = eval(data.decode(codec))  ## decode and make a list
    for d in l:                   ## enumerate through list to get dictionary
        if d[key] == key_v:       ## only if key is the required, matching value
            return d[req]         ## return the values required

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # input data
    data = b'[{"id":"1","array1_1":"0","array1_2":"1","array2_1":"2","array2_2":"3","array3_1":"44","array3_2":"55"},{"id":"asd","array1_1":"234","array1_2":"[[0, 26, 60, 45], [0, -45, 45]]","array2_1":"[[23, 345], [543, 321]]","array2_2":"jytj","array3_1":"5","array3_2":"6"},{"id":"bb","array1_1":"bbb","array1_2":"ad","array2_1":"[[23, 345], [543, 321]]","array2_2":"[[0, 45], [45]]","array3_1":"[[34, 45], [66, 88]]","array3_2":"sfw"},{"id":"aa","array1_1":"aa","array1_2":"[[0, 26, 60, 45], [0, -45, 45]]","array2_1":"gfd","array2_2":"[[0, 45], [45]]","array3_1":"sdf","array3_2":"[[26, 60], [0], [56, 34, 45]]"},{"id":"ss","array1_1":"00","array1_2":"[[0, 45], [0, -45, 45], [0, -45, 45, -26]]","array2_1":"[[31, 233], [152, 151], [190, 204], [205, 87], [231, 48], [255, 194]]","array2_2":"[[0, 45], [45], [45], [26, 45, 63], [45], [0, 26, 45, 63]]","array3_1":"[[29, 194], [32, 234], [165, 229], [232, 46], [258, 190]]","array3_2":"[[45], [0, 45], [0, 26, 45], [0, -63, 45, 63], [0, 26, 45]]"}]'

    # selection criteria
    selection_key   = 'id'     ## this is the key to use for selection of the list element
    selection_value = 'ss'     ## this is the value of the selection key
    required_key = 'array1_2'  ## this is the key you want values returned

    # get required values from data
    result = get_my_values(data, selection_key, selection_value, required_key)  ## get values

    # make a list if possible
    try:
        result = eval(result)  ## make it a list if possible
    except NameError:
        pass  ## cannot be made a list, and is a single value

    # print results
    print(result)
    print(type(result))
```

Example output:

```
[[0, 45], [0, -45, 45], [0, -45, 45, -26]]
<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `print(c1)` instead.

c1 is already a list, so with `print(list(c1))` you are re-listing it.